# AMIMOTO + ELB 環境下での WordPress 管理画面が SSL で開けない

Tags: php, aws, nginx, wordpress, amazon-elb

はじめまして。

最近 WordPress を使い始めました。

構築の省力化のため網元を使用したのですが、SSL を設定して管理画面にアクセス・ログインすると
「このページにアクセスするための十分なアクセス権がありません。」
と表示されて管理画面が表示できない状況で困っています。
（HTTP では表示できますがセキュリティのためすぐにでも HTTPS にしたい状況です）

DEBUG モードにしても特にエラーがでるわけでもなく、原因が特定できない状況です。
お力添えをお願いします。

環境

OS : AMIMOTO HVM 1.2.2 (CentOS 系 Linux)
WordPress : 4.4.2
Nginx 1.9.14, PHP 5.6.20, Percona MySQL 5.6.29, WP-CLI 0.23.0

なお、ELB 配下に配置しているため、wp-config.php に以下のように設定を追加しています (SSL Termination 対応)

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' ) {
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
}
```

現状としては
HTTP / HTTPS 両方でサイトにアクセスが可能
管理画面（ログイン）も HTTP / HTTPS 両方で可能
ログイン後のダッシュボードが HTTPS で閲覧不可能（アクセス権がありませんエラー）

となっています。 HTTP ではアクセスできるため、Cookie のあたりの問題かと思っているのですが解決できません。

よろしくお願いします。